# Simplification of bivariate normal $\phi_2(x,y,\rho)$ at $y=y_F$ (i.e. fixing one of the axes)

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, dimensionality-reduction, multivariate-normal-distribution, bivariate

Suppose we start off with the traditional standard bivariate normal density function:

$$\phi_2(x,y|\rho,\mu_x=0,\mu_y=0,\sigma_x=1,\sigma_y=1)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp \left(-\frac{x^2-2\rho x y + y^2}{2(1-\rho^2)}\right)$$

where the $\mu$s are the mean parameters, the $\sigma$s are the standard deviation parameters and $\rho$ is the correlation term between $x$ and $y$.

My question is: what happens to $\phi_2$ when we fix $y=y_F$? In other words, what happens when the only "free" variable in $\phi_2$ is $x$?

---

**Edit**

After banging my head against my table for quite a bit, I noticed that I was confusing two different concepts:

- a bivariate normal density with $y$ fixed at some point $y_F$
- the conditional bivariate density with a given $y$ (i.e. $dens(X=x|Y=y_F)$)

These are two very different beasts, but I was treating them as the same.

Comment: Are you asking for the pdf of $X\mid Y$ where $(X,Y)$ is bivariate normal?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I know we can express the pdf of $X|Y$ by the traditional conditional distribution rule $\phi_2(X|Y)=\frac{\phi_2(X,Y)}{\phi_1(Y)}$. But this solution still requires the calculation of a bivariate pdf $\phi_2$. I'm trying to simplify things such that, in the end, I only need to deal with univariate distributions $\phi_1$.

Comment: The ratio is obvious since it is equal to the inverse of the value of PDF of Y at Y=1 and as long as you keep Y=1, no matter what X you take, the ratio will remain the same. Moreover, in your comment you write $\phi_2(X|Y)$, which is wrong. Following your notations, since X|Y is a univariate random variable, it's distribution should be represented by $\phi_1(X|Y)$ instead.

Comment: A bivariate random variable (X,Y) and a random variable (X|Y) are two different random variables. I think you are confusing between the two.

Comment: You're right, @SanketAgrawal, I was getting my notation mixed up. I finally understand what the heck was going on. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can calculate $\phi_2(x,y,\rho)$ when $y$ is fixed at $y_F$.

First, from basic conditioning rules, we know that:

$$ \text{dens}(X=x|Y=y_F) = \frac{\text{dens}(X=x,Y=y_F)}{\text{dens}(Y=y_F)} \Rightarrow$$

$$ \text{dens}(X=x,Y=y_F) = \text{dens}(X=x|Y=y_F) \cdot \text{dens}(Y=y_F) \Rightarrow$$

$$ \phi_2(x,y_F,\rho) = \text{dens}(X=x|Y=y_F) \cdot \phi_1(y_F|\text{mean}=0,\text{var}=1) $$

We can find a way to deal with that central $\text{dens}$ term by thinking about the [conditional probability of bivariate normal distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case_2). In the more general case, if two variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ are jointly normally distributed, we know that the conditional probability can be described as:

$$ \text{dens}\left(X_1=x_1 | X_2=x_2\right) = \phi_1\left(x_1|\text{mean}= \mu_1 + \frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2} \cdot \rho \cdot (x_2 - \mu_2), \text{var}=(1-\rho^2)\cdot {\sigma_2}^2\right) $$

where $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are the means of $X_1$ and $X_2$ and  ${\sigma_1}^2$ and ${\sigma_2}^2$ are the variances of $X_1$ and $X_2$, and $\rho$ is the correlation term between $X_1$ and $X_2$.

In our specific case, we have determined that $\mu_1=0$, $\sigma_1=1$, $\mu_2=0$ and $\sigma_1=1$.

Now, using the information above, we can swap out that $\text{dens}$ term and arrive at an actual function:

$$ \phi_2(x,y_F,\rho)=\phi_1(x|\text{mean}= \rho \cdot y_F, \text{var}=1-\rho^2) \cdot \phi_1(y_F|\text{mean}= 0, \text{var}=1)$$