# Is it possible to calculate a bivariate normal density using only the univariate normal density function?

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-probability, bivariate, conditioning

Suppose $(X,Y)$ are two jointly normally distributed random variables. Suppose further that we want to calculate the density of $(X=x,Y=y)$. Is it possible to calculate this density if we do not have access to the bivariate normal density function, but instead only have access to the univariate normal density function? Stated more clearly: can I represent a bivariate normal density only using the univariate density function? Is this possibe?

PS: This question is mostly answered in [this other thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/403748/simplification-of-bivariate-normal-phi-2x-y-rho-at-y-y-f-i-e-fixing-on), but the objective of that other thread was a little different, so I figured posting a more generic answer here would be warranted.

Comment: How can you not have access to the bivariate normal density function?  It's just a function, you can write it out on a piece of paper and calculate it on a calculator...

Comment: I'm thinking in terms of a computational environment. So consider that I have a pre-written function for the univariate density, but not one for the bivariate density. I'm trying to find a way to calculate the bivariate density without coding my own version of it from scratch, just using stuff that is already *available*. Does that make more sense? Thanks for the question!

Comment: You only need a computational environment that supports addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and exponentiation.  That would be just about anything, including an antique calculator.  This leads me to wonder whether you are really trying to ask about the *probability* function rather than the density.  The probability function is an integral of an error function and that's not commonly available in calculators.

Comment: The specific problem I was trying to solve is described [in this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3190305/partial-derivatives-for-box-integral-of-a-bivariate-normal-distribution). It involves calculating partial derivatives of box integrals of bivariate densities (as you suspected, integrals are involved). The issue is that the partial derivatives become much more tractable if I can express the bivariate densities in terms of a multiplication of two univariate densities. That's why I was trying to consider the case where I didn't "have access" to the bivariate distribution.

Comment: Maybe a better way to title to my question would be: "How can I express a bivariate normal density by only using univariate normal density functions?"

Comment: In the thread you link to, those derivatives are explicitly expressed in terms of the univariate Normal probability and density functions.  Thus, it already answers your underlying question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is indeed possible. Based on [this other answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/403748/simplification-of-bivariate-normal-phi-2x-y-rho-at-y-y-f-i-e-fixing-on) that uses the [conditional distribution rule for bivariate normal distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case_2) , we can substitute the bivariate normal density function by the multiplication of two univariate normal density functions:

$$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\text{ }&\phi_2\left(x,y \text{ }\bigg| \text{ }\text{mean}=\begin{bmatrix}
 \mu_x \\ \mu_y \end{bmatrix} ,\text{cov}=\begin{bmatrix}
 {\sigma_x}^2 & \rho\cdot{\sigma_x}\cdot{\sigma_y} \\ \rho\cdot{\sigma_x}\cdot{\sigma_y} & {\sigma_y}^2 \end{bmatrix} \right) = \\ 
= &\text{ }&\phi_1\left(x\bigg|\text{mean}= \mu_x + \frac{\sigma_x}{\sigma_y} \cdot \rho \cdot (y - \mu_y), \text{var}=(1-\rho^2)\cdot {\sigma_y}^2\right) \\ 
\cdot &\text{ }&\phi_1\left(y\bigg|\text{mean}=\mu_y,\text{var}={\sigma_y}^2\right)
\end{split}
\end{equation}$$

where:

- $\phi_1$  and $\phi_2$ represent the univariate and bivariate normal density functions, respectively;
- $\mu_x$ and $\mu_y$ represent the means of the $X$ and $Y$ random variables, respectively;
- ${\sigma_x}^2$ and ${\sigma_y}^2$ represent variances of the $X$ and $Y$ random variables, respectively;
- $\rho$ represents the correlation term between the $X$ and $Y$ random variables.

Note how the right-hand side of the equation does not involve the bivariate normal density $\phi_2$ function, and instead only uses the univariate normal density $\phi_1$ function.

The equivalence above isn't an approximation - it's an actual equivalence. The results you obtain using both methods shouldn't be *approximately* equal - they should be identical.

Comment: This is possible because there is a marginal density that is Normal and all the conditional densities are Normal, too.

Comment: Can you edit your latex such that it can be read without scrolling?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Does that look better?

Comment: Much better!  thanks!